# Returning to Italy as a tourist after a 90 day stay

Tags: schengen, paperwork, 90-180-visa-rules, venezuelan-citizens

My wife entered Aug.18, 2018 Europe (Italy) and left Nov.16, 2018 as a tourist from Venezuela.  Now she wants to return as a tourist on Jan. 3, 2019.  Will she be allowed to enter as a tourist again?

Comment: That was a 91-day stay (the day of entry and the day of exit both count as an entire day).  In any event, she can't return until February 15th, I believe.  But if you are also in Italy and are a citizen of an EU or Schengen country, the 90/180 rule will not apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work)

Comment: @phoog If she has a decent amount of stamps in her passport, officers are unlikely to notice the 1-day overstay

Comment: @Crazydre agreed, but if they notice that she's reentering within 90 days of her last exit, they are likely to look closely enough to see that she's returning too soon.

Comment: @phoog Hence why I'm saying that she's not to return until the 180-day clock is up

Comment: She can if you are a EEA citizen and she is travelling with you or you are already there, otherwise no.

Answer (score 4):

If she's not an EU/Schengen citizen or Schengen resident, then no, she won't be let back in until 15 February, because from the first entry, the total stay during the next 180 days cannot exceed 90 days.